# "He must be in the room". "He must be inside the room" what is to be be used?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, sentence-structure

> "He must be in the room."
>
> "He must be inside the room."

- Which one is correct?
- Which preposition is suitable for this
  sentence?

  I think, "He must be in the room." This one is usually
  used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "in the room" is more commonly used.  "inside" is not wrong, but it's a longer word that adds no more meaning (at least when used in reference to a room.)

You would use "inside" as a contrast to "outside", for instance, as in the following which makes an implicit reference to a house...

A:  "It's cold outside."

B: "Come in; it's warm inside."